# Laravel Mailable - Trying to get property 'email' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

I have the following mailable:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class UserLoginDetailsMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected String $username;
    protected String $email;
    protected String $password;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param String $username
     * @param String $email
     * @param String $password
     */
    public function __construct(String $username, String $email, String $password)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->from('test@test.com', env('TENANT_NAME'))
            ->replyTo(env('TENANT_EMAIL'))
            ->to($this->email)
            ->subject('Test')
            ->view('api.emails.user-login-details')
            ->with([
                'username' => $this->username,
                'password' => $this->password,
            ]);
    }
}
```

Being fired like so:

```
Mail::queue(new UserLoginDetailsMail('test', "test@test.com", "test"));
```

However my queued job is experiencing the following error:

`ErrorException: Trying to get property 'email' of non-object in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php:612`

```
/**
     * Set the recipients of the message.
     *
     * All recipients are stored internally as [['name' => ?, 'address' => ?]]
     *
     * @param  object|array|string  $address
     * @param  string|null  $name
     * @param  string  $property
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function setAddress($address, $name = null, $property = 'to')
    {
        foreach ($this->addressesToArray($address, $name) as $recipient) {
            $recipient = $this->normalizeRecipient($recipient);

            $this->{$property}[] = [
                'name' => $recipient->name ?? null,
                'address' => $recipient->email,
            ];
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

This queued mail is being fired within another queued job, not sure if this would have any impact.

Thanks

Comment: What does `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php` line #612 look like for your version? The current version has that line as a annotation which isn't helpful.

Comment: Also just to confirm that your ENV TENANT_NAME and TENANT_EMAIL is set correctly?

Comment: ENV variables are all set correctly. Running on Laravel version 7

Comment: Ok, then what does line 612 have?

Comment: I have updated my question to include this.

```'address' => $recipient->email,```

Comment: Which line is 612? I assume it's `'address' => $recipient->email,`

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Whenever I face a framework problem like this, I dump/log values throughout the entire process to try and determine the point where it goes wrong. Usually gives me an idea of what might be defined in a wrong way or at least something new to search for.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine. You probably made changes in your code though, without restarting the queue. As per the Laravel documentation:

> Since queue workers are long-lived processes, they will not notice changes to your code without being restarted. So, the simplest way to deploy an application using queue workers is to restart the workers during your deployment process. You may gracefully restart all of the workers by issuing the queue:restart command:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Comment: I have restarted the queue several times, and also after each code change but the issue still persist.

Comment: Also work noting I'm running ```php artisan queue:listen``` This has been restarted after each code change.

Answer (score 0):

Did you cache your config? If so clean it with `php artisan config:clear` and try to send mail again.

it's will work